# Suppress GCC warnings for Qt headers

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wsuggest-override` to an existing project to find missing override.

It is a project with several library and everything is statically linked.

When I activate the flag gcc to parse any external library (and Qt too) and flood me with warning not depending to my code.

There's a way to limit the context of the suggest override at least excluding to check Qt libraries?

Answer (score 1):

you can set in the pro file the qmake flag isystem ([more info can be found here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)) so you can exclude the libs you dont have control over...

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $$PWD/../third_party/my_external_code
```

edit: try as @Moia suggested:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]
```

Comment: How I can do it with the Qt itself?

Comment: @Moia try `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]`